# How do I create a loop using a timer in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, loops, timer

I am quite new to Swift and would love to know how to create a loop that runs some code every 30 seconds? I feel as though it is a basic question but I can't really find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can make Use of ***Timer***

```
Timer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.30, target: self, selector: #selector(timerFired), userInfo: userInfo, repeats: true)
```

`timerFired`: is the method that gets called after interval

```
@objc func timerFired() {
      print("Timer Called with interval 30seconds")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use scheduled timer. In `viewDidLoad()`

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 30, target: self, selector: #selector(YourFuncName), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

and func for selector

```
@objc func YourFuncName() {
      print("every 30seconds")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func startTimer() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 30, target: self, selector: #selector(UpdateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func UpdateTimer() {
    counter += 1
}
```

to start

```
startTimer();
```

and to stop

```
timer.invalidate()
```